# Android Sensor event always return AK8973 3-axis Magnetic field sensor

Tags: android

I tried several time to get `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER`, but it always return AK8973 3-axis Magnetic field sensor. When i shaking mobile device, it always return same AK8973 3-axis Magnetic field sensor. I registered inside resume method, here is code :

```
boolean supported = mSensorMgr.registerListener(this,
    mSensorMgr.getDefaultSensor(SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER),
    sensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
```

However, i couldn't get `(sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)` inside `onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)` method. I couldn't understand why it always return Magnetic field sensor.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem, i mistake in 
mSensorMgr.getDefaultSensor(SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER) instead of SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER, i change Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER and it works.